# Call function from one component from numerous other components to update state

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that would need to be updated from various other components. This component is the header for my web page and I wold like to update the text in the header depending on what the user is doing/where they are navigating.

Right now I have:

**HeaderTitle.js**

```
  class HeaderTitle extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      headerTitle : "Suite"
    };
  }

  setHeaderTitle(text) {
      this.setState({
        headerTitle : text
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>{this.state.headerTitle}</h1>
    )
  }

}
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="main-content">

          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <HeaderTitle/>
          </header>

          <Content/>
        </div>

        <MainMenu/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And lets say, one of the many views I'd like to update the HeaderTitle from:

```
class InventoryContainer extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {

    HeaderTitle.setHeaderTitle("Search Inventory")

  }

  render() {
    return (
    )
  }

}

export default InventoryContainer
```

Comment: How nested would be your `InventoryContainer`? Are you going to use inside the `App`? Also are you using Redux?

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb is that internal component state should be lifted up to application/global state when multiple components interact with that data.

If you are using Redux or another application state manager, then `headerTitle` should live in your Redux state and you would dispatch a redux action to change its value.

If you are not using Redux or something similar, then "headerTitle" should live at the top-most level of your application that interacts with it (i.e. that consumes the data or changes it).

I would suggest moving `this.state = { headerTitle: '' }` and your `setHeaderTitle` method into `App.js`. Then you can pass `this.setHeaderTitle` and `this.state.headerTitle` via props to other components.